# CSS: div width increasing on adding the child div to it

Tags: javascript, html, css

[![enter image description here][1]][1]Hi I am desingning a webpage. I have set the header div width with the screen width using javascript code as follows

```
window.onload=getSize;

function getSize()
{
    var x=window.screen.availWidth;
    var y=window.screen.availHeight;

    document.getElementById("header").style.width=(x-50)+'px';
    document.getElementById("header").style.height=(0.2*y)+'px';
    document.getElementById("wrapper").style.width=(x-50)+'px';
    document.getElementById("wrapper").style.height=(0.6*y)+'px';

}
```

Now what happening is when I am adding the child divs to the parent div(header) the width of header gets increased considerably but i want it to remain fixed according to the display size

here is the css file

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

#header {
    margin: auto; 
    position : relative;
    background-color: #009acd;


}

#logo1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    left: 0.4%;
}

#caption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 30%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#marquee{
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    left: 300px;

    }
#info{
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 1075px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    }
h3{
    position: absolute;
    top: 90px;
    left: 1000px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    }
#menu{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0%;
    left: 0.215%;
    }
#wrapper{
position: relative;
background-color: #FFFFFF;

}
#videos{
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left: 22px;
}
#studymaterial1{
    position: absolute;
    top:148px;
    left: 32px;
}
#downloads{
    position: absolute;
    top: 315px;
    left: 22px;
}
#wowslider-container1{
    left: 233px;
    top: 10px;

}
.formoid-solid-blue{
    position: absolute;
    left: 912px;
    top:    12px;

}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I suppose you must set the width of the child div first and the you must append them to the parent div. That way the width of the inside div cant extend the width of the outside div and so it will not expand.

Comment: but i have already gave the required width to every child width

Comment: Try `max-width and max-height` instead of width and height

Comment: i tried it but still same problem.. when i comment all the child divs under header div ... it works just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking

```
window.screen.availWidth
```

which is a constant and is equal to the **width of your computer screen**. Eg '1366px'

Instead you must use

```
window.innerWidth
```

which gives you the **width of your browser window** when the page loads.

```
var x=window.innerWidth;
var y=window.innerHeight;
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Excuse me it does remain constant. You can change screen size, reload and check.

Comment: but then why white space is appearing just adjacent to the header div you can see it from the picture

Comment: some component of yours is overflowing the border. You need to find it and set it's dimensions accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> You are missing **unit**(`px`/`%`) while assigning the `width`/`height` property.

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("header").style.width=(x-50)+'px';
____________________________________________________^^^^^^
```

Comment: yea I wrote it but still div problem persists